# Date and other column as filter in R shiny

Tags: r

Wanted to check if we can use the below code to filter both date columns and other column..

The below code is not working properly under if statement. Because when I select ALL and alter the date, there is no data at all , Not sure why

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(lubridate)
source("df.R")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    dateRangeInput("Date", "", start = Sys.Date(), end = Sys.Date(), format = "yyyy-mm-dd", separator = "-"),
    selectInput("Tic","",choices = c("ALL",as.character(df$ID)),selected = "ALL"),
    actionButton("Submit","Submit"),
    dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)
```

server.R

```
source("utils.R")
library(dplyr)

server <- function(input, output,session) { 
  df1 <- df %>% filter(Date1 == Sys.Date())
  data_1 <- reactiveVal(df1)


observeEvent(input$Submit,{
  if (input$Tic == "ALL"){
    table_display <- df %>% filter(Date1 %in% input$Date[1] : input$Date[2])
  }

  else if (input$Tic == "ALL" && input$Date[1] == Sys.Date() && input$Date[2] == Sys.Date())
   { 
    table_display <- df %>% filter(Date1 == Sys.Date())
   }

  else if (input$Tic != "ALL" && input$Date[1] == Sys.Date() && input$Date[2] == Sys.Date())
  {
    table_display <- df %>% filter(ID %in% input$Tic & Date1 == Sys.Date())
  }

  else 
  {
    table_display <- df %>% filter(ID %in% input$Tic & Date1 %in% input$Date[1] : input$Date[2])
  }

  data_1(table_display)
})

output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
  datatable(data_1())
})

}
```

df.R

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1541662915.921, 1541562949.500, 
                                         1581145671.845, 1581145671.845, 1541662993.957, 1541662915.921, 
                                        1541662949.842, 1541662949.845, 1541662949.845, 1581145671.957
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Date1 = structure(c(17843, 
                                                                       17843, 17844, 17843, 18843, 17843, 18300, 17843, 17843, 18300
), class = "Date"), ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("AAA", "BBB"), class = "factor"), 
Value = c(68, 70175, 71107, 702175, 72638, 7238, 739, 738469, 
          75901, 7106), Status = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Approved", "Pending"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                   -10L), class = "data.frame")
df$Date <- NULL
df$Status <- NULL
```

I mean to fitler the column called "ID" and Date from (Start date to End date)

Comment: `filter(ID %in% input$Tic, input$Date[1] <= Date1, Date1 <= input$Date[2])`?

Comment: While using the vector-AND `&` is also correct, `dplyr::filter` is nice enough to logically AND all of its arguments, so you can use `&` or `,` to separate what should be `logical` vectors, they will be ANDed underneath.

Comment: That doesn't change my suggestion.

Comment: Actually I tried with your inputs but not working

Comment: When you click "Submit": yes, `input$Tic` is "ALL"; yes, `!is.null(input$Date)`. So far, so good, we're in the first conditional block. However, your date range `input$Date[1] : input$Date[2]`, based on your default values, are *today* and not (yet) any of the dates in `df`. If I change the second date to be tomorrow or later, then it returns at least two rows. Am I missing something?

Comment: Got it thanks a lot